# How can I delete my application's data from RAM in android?

Tags: android, ram

When I close the application and run it again on Android phone, some old string values is coming again to screen. (If I don't clean the ram). How can I reach my app without any old data?

Comment: what string values? String values in textviews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should review and properly handle the [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

Android does indeed keep your app in memory after the user navigates away. This significantly improves performance when the user wants to open your app again.

If there is some data that your application should clear once the user navigates away, you should override [`onPause()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29), [`onStop()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop%28%29), or [`onDestroy()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29) as appropriate.